# MSBUILD batch targets

Tags: msbuild

I want to deploy an application to a list of servers.  I have all of the build issues taken care of, but I'm having trouble publishing to a list of servers.  I want to read the list of servers from an external file and call a target passing the name of each server in.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <File Include="$(SolutionFolder)CP\Build\DenormDevServers.txt" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="DeployToServer" Inputs="Servers" Outputs="Nothing">
    <Message Text="Deployment to server done here.  Deploying to server: @(Servers)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="Test">
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="@(File)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="Servers" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>

    <CallTarget Targets="DeployToServer" ContinueOnError="true"></CallTarget>
</Target>
```

I can't seem to get it to "Deploy" to each server in the list.  The output looks like this:

```
Deployment to server done here.  Deploying to server:
```

Notice there is no server name, nor is done more than once.  There are 2 lines in DenormDevServers.txt

Comment: Do you want MsBuild target batching, as could be interpreted from the question's title? Target batching is a specific feature where an up to date check is performed between the target's inputs and outputs, and all the tasks in the target are invoked for a single input before moving to the next input. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms228229(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using inputs and outputs properly.

Your deploy target should look something like

```
<Target Name="DeployToServer" Inputs="@(Servers)" Outputs="%(Identity)">
    <Message Text="Deployment to server done here.  Deploying to server: %(Servers.Identity)" />
</Target>
```

And you should use dependencies rather than explicitly calling targets, e.g.

```
<Target Name="Test" DependsOn="LoadServers;DeployToServer"/>
```

And create a new target LoadServers that reads the file into the @(Servers) item.

[edit] The reason for Outputs="%(Identity)" is to get target batching without actually performing up to date checks.

Answer (score 0):

This achives your result. I think your trying to use tasks a bit too much like methods.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTarget="Test" >

<ItemGroup>
    <File Include=".\CP\Build\DenormDevServers.txt" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="DeployToServer" DependsOnTargets="Test">
   <Message Text="Deployment to server done here.  Deploying to server: @(Servers)" /> 
</Target>

<Target Name="Test">
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="@(File)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="Servers" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
</Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the cleanest approach.  Use DependsOnTargets to ensure that Test target is run before DeployToServer.

To get the values of each item in an ItemGroup you must use %(Identity).

The following code will produce the output required.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <File Include="$(SolutionFolder)CP\Build\DenormDevServers.txt" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="DeployToServer"
        DependsOnTargets="Test">
    <Message Text="Deployment to server done here.  Deploying to server: %(Servers.Identity)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="Test">
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="@(File)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines"
                ItemName="Servers" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>       
</Target>
```